# Frequency response simple question

Tags: function

I'm looking at answers to calculating the frequency response, but i don't understand one line. what are they doing to go from the first line to the second line?

[image]

Comment: Note that if \$\omega_h=\frac12\omega\$ then \$\frac12\left(1+e^{-j\,\omega}\right)=\frac12 e^{-j\,\omega_h}\left(e^{j\,\omega_h}+e^{-j\,\omega_h}\right)= e^{-j\,\omega_h}\cdot\operatorname{cos}\left(\omega_h\right)\$. Just basic math identities, really. But useful to "perceive" at times.

Answer (score 0):

They are factoring out \$e^\frac{-j\omega}{2}\$.

Note that \$e^\frac{-j\omega}{2} \cdot e^\frac{j\omega}{2} = 1\$

and \$e^\frac{-j\omega}{2} \cdot e^\frac{-j\omega}{2} = e^{-j\omega}\$

Comment: are you working it out from the second line to the first line?

Comment: It works both ways. I'd have to see more context in order to understand *why* this seems useful.

Comment: sorry i don't do maths a lot so sorry if i'm not understanding. if i'm only looking at the first line without the second, what is it do, multiply by e-jw/2?

Answer (score 0):

You may be confused about how exponentials interact.

The important one for this is \$e^x \cdot e^x = e^{x+x} = e^{2x}\$

Take your equations and work them backwards to see what happened. You have

\$H(\omega)=0.5e^\frac{-j\omega}{2}(e^\frac{j\omega}{2}+e^\frac{-j\omega}{2})\$

Distribute the \$e^\frac{-j\omega}{2}\$ term inside the parentheses and combine the terms

\$(e^\frac{-j\omega}{2} \cdot e^\frac{j\omega}{2} + e^\frac{-j\omega}{2} \cdot e^\frac{-j\omega}{2}) = 
(e^{\frac{-j\omega}{2}+\frac{j\omega}{2}} + e^{\frac{-j\omega}{2}+\frac{-j\omega}{2}}) = (e^0 + e^\frac{-2j\omega}{2})=(1+e^{-j\omega})\$

So adding the rest of the equation you have

\$ H(\omega) = 0.5(1+e^{-j\omega})\$

In other words, that \$e\$ term was divided-out/factored-out of the parentheses.